# swift table view cells does not let me use indexPath.row

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

i am trying to populate data into cells inside of a table view. I created a chosenPlanData var which is initialized to an object with the data inside of it..  The object has properties such as "name" and "event location". An issue occurs when inside of 'cellForRowAt'. It does not let me add [indexPath.row] to the cell i am creating, which in turn does not populate the cells correctly.

For instance - i removed indexPath.row from the first cell.nameLbl.text call - and in turn every single name label in the table view was the same.  here is piece of the code

```
 var chosenPlanData = ChosenPlan()   

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "individualPlansCell") as? PlanitsHomeViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }


          cell.nameLbl.text = chosenPlanData.nameOfEvent[indexPath.row] // error Cannot assign value of type 'Character' to type 'String?'

        cell.dateAndTimeLbl.text = chosenPlanData.eventStartsAt[indexPath.row] as? String // error 'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, see the documentation comment for discussion

      cell.nameLbl.text = chosenPlanData.nameOfEvent // This works - but every single cell has the same nameLbl though


        return cell

    }


   // Here is the call back where i initialize the value for chosenPlanData

        let EventbriteTVC = segue.destination as! EventbriteTableView

        EventbriteTVC.callbackChosePlan = { result in


            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.individualPlanitsTableView.reloadData()
            }

            self.chosenPlanData = result



        }
```

import Foundation
import UIKit

class ChosenPlan {

```
var nameOfEvent : String = ""
var eventStartsAt : String = ""
var eventLocationIs : String = ""
var eventURL : String = ""
var imageForPlan : String?


convenience init( eventName: String, eventTime: String, eventLocation: String, eventImage: String){

    self.init()

    self.nameOfEvent = eventName
    self.eventStartsAt = eventTime
    self.eventLocationIs = eventLocation
    //self.eventURL = eventLink
    self.imageForPlan = eventImage

    //eventLink: String,
}
```

}

Comment: Please show us your "ChosenPlan" class.

Comment: you need to convert your chosenPlanData.nameOfEvent[indexPath.row] from character to String thats it

Comment: @Khushbu just updated question now with it. thanks

Comment: @ReinierMelian it will not let me do that.. how exactly are you suggesting i do that?

Comment: `nameOfEvent` is String and `chosenPlanData.nameOfEvent[indexPath.row]` you treating it as array, how does it work?

Comment: @dahiya_boy that is because this will be presented within a table view. name of event is a parameter within an object i created.

Comment: @CodingwhileLoading Go through my answer, you will be more cleared,

Comment: It is not clear how you want to populate the tableView ? Here you have a single ChosenPlan that you use for all cells ! So you probably want an Array of ChosenPlan, as explained elsewhere. Up to you to create and populate this array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `chosenPlanData` variable is a single instance of `ChosenPlan` - You cannot subscript a single instance.

It needs to be an array of `ChosenPlan`:

```
var chosenPlanData =  [ChosenPlan]()
```

Then you can index into this array:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "individualPlansCell") as? PlanitsHomeViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

          cell.nameLbl.text = chosenPlanData[indexPath.row].nameOfEvent 
          cell.dateAndTimeLbl.text = chosenPlanData[indexPath.row].eventStartsAt
```

Comment: I miss understood what the OP was trying until I find out that he was originally wrong about the TableView concept the error about the characters and Strings was because he was accesing to a String in [indexPath.row] which is a Character lol, +1 for best reading than me

Answer (score 2):

extending my comment

1. `var chosenPlanData = ChosenPlan()`

`chosenPlanData` is object of `ChosenPlan`

2. Now in `cellForRow` you writing `chosenPlanData.nameOfEvent[indexPath.row]` but `nameOfEvent` is String as per your `ChosenPlan` that you mentioned in question.

For more info,

`chosenPlanData.nameOfEvent[indexPath.row]` this line represents you using the **n th** (indexPath.row) object of `nameOfEvent` which is object of `chosenPlanData`

Hope now will be more cleared.

> Solution

1. `var chosenPlanData =  [ChosenPlan]()` <- create array
2. In `cellForRow` `chosenPlanData[indexPath.row].nameOfEvent`  that means you'r using `nameOfEvent` of **nth** object of `chosenPlanData`.

Comment: You were right Only issue now is attempting to make sure the number of rows in sections adds up. im getting an index out of range issue when i do this. but am working on it now. thank you

Answer (score 0):

if

```
var chosenPlanData = [ChosenPlan]()
```

Try this:-

```
cell.nameLbl.text = "\(chosenPlanData[indexPath.row].nameOfEvent)"
```

or

```
cell.nameLbl.text = "\(chosenPlanData[indexPath.row].nameOfEvent ?? "")"
```

Comment: It gave me an error - 'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, see the documentation comment for discussion

Comment: chosenPlanData[indexPath.row].nameOfEvent Cause nameOfEvent is not array type

Comment: When i enter it in that way, it says - Type 'ChosenPlan' has no subscript members

Comment: Your chosenPlanData shouldbe like this var chosenPlanData = [ChosenPlan]()   then only you can use indexpath on chosenPlanData

Comment: it does, however when i type it in like that, the name changes each time a new cell is added. So if at first the table view has 1 cell with label "Dog", and i add another cell with label "Cat". I end up having 2 cells but they both say "cat".. it basically gets ride of the previous name label

Comment: You are creating object of ChosePlan class.. if you have to store two values then you need to create array of ChosenPlan class object like  var chosenPlanData = [ChosenPlan]()... So using indexpath you can access dog, cat values

Answer (score 0):

Type handling is very important in Swift. Try this.

```
cell.nameLbl.text = String(chosenPlanData.nameOfEvent[indexPath.row])
let index = chosenPlanData.eventStartsAt.index(chosenPlanData.eventStartsAt.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
cell.dateAndTimeLbl.text = String(chosenPlanData.eventStartsAt[index])
```